# HDL Compiler Error 806 for Verilog HDL Test Fixture (Shift Register)

Tags: verilog, xilinx, digital, xilinx-ise

So I am doing a pre-lab assignment for my digital systems course in which we are supposed to test certain components and ultimately create a counter from them. The issue I'm having is that the code the professor gave us won't compile. This specific test fixture (ISE Design Suite 14.7) is describing a shift register.

```
module kg4014TB;

// Inputs
reg Clock;
reg Ser_In;
reg [7:0] P;
reg ParLoadCTRL;

// Outputs
wire Q7;
wire Q6;
wire Q5;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
kg4014 uut (
    .Clock(Clock), 
    .Ser_In(Ser_In), 
    .P(P), 
    .ParLoadCTRL(ParLoadCTRL), 
    .Q7(Q7), 
    .Q6(Q6), 
    .Q5(Q5)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    Clock = 0;
    Ser_In = 0;
    P = 8'b11011111
    #100;
    ParLoadCTRL = 1;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #700; 
    ParLoadCTRL = 0; //shift mode
    #15000;  
    // Add stimulus here    
    end
    always begin
    #500 Clock = ~Clock;
    end   
    endmodule
```

Here's the error message(s):

```
ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 - "C:/Xilinx/14.7/.v" Line 54: Syntax error near "#".

ERROR:HDLCompiler:598 - "C:/Xilinx/14.7/.v" Line 25: Module <kg4014TB> ignored due to previous errors.
```

Although I don't think it makes any difference, I'll just point out that I deleted some of the file path and the file name for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 0):

This line is missing a semicolon at the end:

```
P = 8'b11011111;
```